# Why this post closed as "not constructive"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer, not-constructive

I had written a post (question and answer both, it's like an article)  [PDO tutorial for the beginners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110188/is-there-a-pdo-tutorial-for-the-beginners/14110189#14110189)  which is about how to use pdo and why not use `mysql_*`.

It's like a reference post for those who are using `MYSQL_*` function and I have noted that ~8/10 are still using `mysql_*` function with php. That whole long thing takes approximately 6 hours  to write and closed as not constructive. Is such kind of post are not nonconstructive on Stack Overflow? Am I supposed to not write or if I did delete it?

Comment: Maybe Stack Overflow is not the place for tutorials of this specific kind, which fits a blog post somewhere more than Q&A form. Problem is you have great answer, but without a question. Like suggested in one of the answers here, it might fit as a tag wiki.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to salvage the question, but I just don't see one. The answer is nothing short of fantastic. You did a great job, next time just make sure the question is not overly broad. I think what we'll do is merge, because your answer is epic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the answer being *very, very, very nice*, the question sucks. It shows close to zero research effort and is subjective or lacks a definitive answer.

> It is often recommended to instead use PDO. Can someone explain what it actually is and why should I be using it?
>
> If I really need it, what do need to get started with it?

Those are not valid questions.

Have you considered adding your awesome answer to the [php](/questions/tagged/php)/[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)/[mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli)/[pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) tags instead?

Comment: this question is edited as many  time .. every edited question got down vote ..

Comment: I'm sorry, what?

Comment: edit history http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14110188/revisions

Comment: If you try to tell me that the downvotes are purely because the question was edited, then I'll have to disagree with you.

Comment: no..no.. i am telling that question was not properly so edited by other to make it clear and every time ... the edited question got downvote not because of edit

Comment: Oh, you mean that every *revision* of the question got downvotes? That's because the question sucks.

Comment: yup...exactly ..and now it got delete vote too..:(

Comment: @NullPointer Don't worry about the delete votes. Even if it's deleted I'm going to merge it, I'm just making sure it's going to the best canonical question.

Comment: @TimPost thankyou tim.. its really very nice of you

Answer (score 6):

Even if you ask-and-answer, your question and answer are judged separately. Your question is not that good quality, I'm afraid. For one, it has quite a few grammar issues that makes it hard to understand.

If you want to post a self-answered post, you need to have a good question framed. Currently, you don't; it's more like you have an answer looking for a question.

> It is often recommended to instead use PDO. Can someone explain what it actually is and why should I be using it?

This is rather broad, and subjective ("why should I be using it").

> If I really need it, what do need to get started with it?

This is a getting-started post, which is generally NARQ/NC.

---

Also, don't delete your own closed questions. They will probably be undeleted, SE has the right to control how your content is displayed.

Maybe you can add your answer to a tag wiki instead?

Comment: That is right: Question, and answer are judged separately. The fact the OP is answering her/his own question doesn't mean a question that should be closed as not a real question, or not constructive is not closed.